# Streaming microphone audio from Raspberry to PC and send back a responde created with a TTS software

Tags: audio, streaming, microphone

The Pi will have a button and a microphone. The ideal scenario is like this:

1. Someone presses a button
2. The (USB) mic starts recording the audio (the recording needs to be saved for later research purposes)
3. I listen to the recording in real time (on my Windows PC) or the created file gets send to my PC
4. I create an answer with a Text-To-Speech software and stream that back to the Pi (The pi will be connected to a speaker) If that's not possible I could stream this audio via bluetooth to a bluetooth speaker

EDIT: I've read about IceCast 2 and DarkIce, however, I only found old tutorials that have not been updated in a long time

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But what exactly is the question? Do you expect that we program it for you? Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a solution to stream the audio input from a microphone (that is connected via a USB soundcard) to a Windows PC. All the tutorials I found don't seem to work anymore...